# A daily "morning read" e-mail from Pocket

Tags: rss, if-this-then-that, pocket

I use [Pocket](http://getpocket.com/) to save a list of articles I want to read, and my list has grown entirely too long. I'm trying to force myself to read an article a day to help clear out some of those articles; a great way to do that would be to [set up a daily e-mail](http://blog.knowtify.io/i-wish-i-had-a-daily-digest-from-pocket/) that includes a small number of randomly-chosen unread articles that I could quickly read through (or delete from Pocket, if they're outdated or I've already read them).

Here's what I have so far:

- [Pocket has an RSS feed](http://help.getpocket.com/customer/portal/articles/482632-can-i-subscribe-to-my-list-via-rss-) that only shows the thirty most-recently added unread articles.
- [Pocket has an API](https://getpocket.com/developer/docs/v3/retrieve) that I could use to retrieve all my articles and pick a random one, but that would involve writing a local script or setting up an online program.
- IFTTT has [great Pocket integration](https://ifttt.com/pocket) and can do lots of things with newly added articles on Pocket. I can use it to send me [new Pocket articles in a daily or weekly digest](https://ifttt.com/email_digest), but the goal here is to dig deep into the pile of unreads to find something interesting, not to send myself articles I don't want to read.

Do you know of any way to pick a **random** article from an RSS feed and display it or e-mail it to me? Is there any way to get Pocket to return more than 30 articles in an RSS feed, or a third-party software for doing that? Is there a Pocket competitor that has any piece of this functionality, or -- ideally -- a proper one-article-at-a-time daily summary?

Comment: For best results, you might want to remove the bit where you're asking for an app or service. I expect you'd need some third-party solution, but questions asking for web app recommendations are off-topic here. Although I think you have a well-defined problem statement, some folks might not be able to see past that. Focus on the problem you're trying to solve rather than the solution you think you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[getpocketrocket.com](http://getpocketrocket.com/) is a service that sends you one article per day to your provided email and subsequently archives the article in your Pocket account. As of July 2015, the service is free of charge.